# C++, two just writers threads without lock

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have 3 threads.

- thread A and thread B are just writers.
- thread C is a just reader.
- variable is time_t.

I need to verify there is no data corruptions.
If data is from thread A or from thread B, so it is OK.

But, if the result at the variable is data that is no from thread A neither not from thread B so it is corrupted

As i thought because that time_t can be write at one assembly operation
so it will be OK.

Is that right?

Thanks

Comment: Can it? I don't recall reading anything that said `time_t` operations *have* to be atomic.

Comment: *As i thought because that time_t can be write at one assembly operation so it will be OK.*  No.  Even if it is just one *instruction*, that does mean it's just one *memory access*  Even simple `int` instruction aren't guaranteed to be atomic, which is why things like `atomic` exist.

Comment: What OS, compiler, and CPU?

Comment: Even if you are absolutely sure that loads and stores are atomic on your particular architecture for `time_t` objects (are you?) and that you use only load/store (not, e.g., read-modify-write) operations, then there are reordering issues (such as out-of-order execution), which can easily introduce race conditions in your code (are you sure it's not your case?). That's where memory fences come into play.

Answer (score 6):

If you have two potentially concurrent writes<sup>(1)</sup> to a shared location without synchronisation between them, you have Undefined Behaviour and anything can happen. So this is a bad idea.

Note that even if you can't imagine bad execution based on your knowledge of the underlying architecture, the optimiser can get in the way, because it is allowed to assume UB doesn't happen.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that even one writer and one reader without synchronisation is exactly the same UB.

Comment: One write and one read without synchronization is also a data race.

Answer (score 4):

`time_t` is an arithmetic type, which can basically be integer or floating-point. You can therefore try to define an atomic `time_t` as (if C++11 is available):

```
using atomic_time_t = std::atomic<time_t>;
```

This is portable as long as `time_t` is *trivially copyable*, which likely is due to being an *arithmetic type*. It will work even if not being *lock-free*. (Floating-point specializations for `std::atomic` adds C++2a.)

---

Example:

```
using atomic_time_t = std::atomic<time_t>;

int main() {
  std::cout << atomic_time_t{}.is_lock_free() << std::endl;
}
```

This prints out 1 with GCC 7.2 x86_64 compiled with `-std=c++11`.

---

If you need to be 100% sure about portability, or don't have C++11, protect accesses (both reads and writes) to your `time_t` variable by mutex provided by your threading library.

Comment: This is a good simple solution but i need it for the older C++ also